# Request bypasses spring security filter

Tags: spring-security

Request of : /myProjectName/person/myProfile/

is ignored(ie I can access it when I should not) by:

```
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/person/myProfile" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
```

However if I write:

```
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/person/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
```

it works.

I have controller with handler mapping:

```
@RequestMapping("/person")
```

and inside of this controller I have method with handler mapping:

```
@RequestMapping(value= "/myProfile")
```

I don't understand it at all. I don't want to put "/person/**" as I will restrict other handler methods which should be available to anonymous.  :-(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with understanding requests.

**First**: case does not matter as it is lowercased automatically unless explicitly stated not to.

**Second**: if you are control freak like me and like to protect every possible request manually make sure to have **distinction between /request and /request/** as Spring security treat them separately(allowing second) - if we write...

```
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/request" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
```

HOWEVER if we write:

```
 <security:intercept-url pattern="/request/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
```

We protect both types, so in my case I should've put

```
<security:intercept-url pattern="/person/myProfile/**" access="isAuthenticated()"/>
```

Good day and be careful ;-) mine was especially ugly as it started to access fields that would throw exception if access was unauthorised.